# NullPointerException - Using Java to Execute SQL

Tags: java, sql

I have the following Code that throws a null pointer exeption

```
public void checkAcc(String sql)
{
    System.out.print(sql);   // the statement executed is "SELECT AccountID FROM BankAccount"    
    try {
        stmt.executeQuery(sql);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("Nope that is broken - " + e);
    }
}
```

Comment: First, you don't catch "Exception". [That's a bad idea] (http://nekulturniy.com/Writings/RebelWithoutAClause/Rebel_without_a_clause.html). And I must guess the line that's giving you the exception is `stmt.executeQuery(sql);`? Also post the stack trace.

Comment: Put a break point in and step through it.

Comment: Yes, i beleive that it is that line, how do you catch exeption? I am fairly new to java

Comment: *stmt* is null. Where have you initialized this statement object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you checked to ensure that `stmt` isn't null? The way that function is written, it must be a field, and you have to make certain that it has been initialized before `checkAcc()` is called.

Comment: Thanks, it was null due to part of the program not running when it was supposed to. Now I feel slightly Silly. But thanks!

Comment: If this answer solved your problem, please click the checkmark to note it as the accepted answer. Thanks!